# Prevent polygon and polyline from repeating on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to prevent repeating polygon and polyline on minzoom in an other worlds on google maps. For a marker there is an `optimized` option. Is the any solution for other objects?

In the picture below marker is not repeating and polyline does.[image]

Comment: It is not repeating, you are just showing multiple maps and a polyline that does exactly what you have told it to do.

Comment: But the marker doesn't do it somehow

Comment: Yes, because it has an optimizing feature - "dont show a marker on the same spot multiple times" ...

Comment: So my question is does polygon and polyline have the same option

Comment: No. Think about it : You have a polyline with some distinct metrics. How should "it" know that you not want it to be drawed on certain circumstances like if you see the worldmap repeated 3 times?  The marker optimization is a little bit different, since it is more common to have many markers on the same spot, thus it gives no meaning to draw markers on the same spot over and over.

Comment: Yeah, I know it might sounds not very reasonable, but leaflet in the same case doesn't repeat any objects since leaflet range is not limited between -180 180. And I need the same behavior for both apis

Comment: anyone know how this could be done?